# Bad image output in QGIS

Tags: qgis, image, rendering, band

I have created an Orthomosaic .tiff file from multi-spectral images using Agisoft Metashape. Now that I am trying to analyze the image using QGIS, I get a bad image, and I do not know how to fix it.
Here is a screenshot of the resulting bad image: https://prnt.sc/16fcamm

What I tried so far is playing around with the min/max values: http://prntscr.com/16fcwo2

Also, I tried stretching to min/max, stretch and clip to min/max. And I am still lost.

I looked up online, but so far found nothing.

Comment: Please post screenshot directly in your question - the external link is extremely slow. Edit your question to add the images.

Comment: Did you try to load the original images to QGIS: what is the result? You could also "stick" together the single input files in QGIS using virtual raster.

Answer (score 2):

When exporting an Orthomosaic through Agisoft Metashape, uncheck the box that says "Save Alpha Channel," and it should work fine.